# Determine bash_profile was sourced by logging in or by script?

Tags: linux, bash

I have many scripts relying on environment variables, which are set in the `.bash_profile` file.

I've also wanted to display a specific message when logging into the server, which I also added to the `.bash_profile`. However, when called upon by the scripts, I do not want this message to be displayed.

I am aware I can just use `source ~/.bash_profile > /dev/null 2>&1`, but that would involve going over all the scripts which is tedious - so I was wondering if there was a way to determine where the script is sourced from.

I'm aiming for something like this (psuedocode):

```
#FROM_TERMINAL should be set to 1 if ran by the user (logging into the server) - otherwise it stays empty.
if [[ $FROM_TERMINAL = 1 ]]; then
    echo "some message"
else
    :
fi
```

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `man bash`, it says:

```
An interactive shell is one started without non-option arguments (unless -s is specified) and without the -c option whose standard input and error are both connected to terminals (as determined by isatty(3)), or one started with the -i option.
PS1 is set and $- includes i if bash is interactive, allowing a shell script or a startup file to test this state.
```

The `$-` flag contain the shell options set and is explained at
https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html.

Check the contents of the `$-` variable like so:

```bsh
$ echo "$-"
himBHs
```

Determine if `i` is set like so:

```bsh
if [[ $- == *i* ]]
then
    # I was called interactively, do the echoing etc.
fi
```

You can also check if the `$PS1` var was set, I find that not so reliable. See https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/intandnonint.html#IITEST.

Comment: Thank you so much! precisely what I was asking about. I missed it in the manpage.